# jQuery image height change on scroll

Tags: jquery, html

I have a fixed header on my website, and im trying to make the logo image resize as you scroll down to a certain point, then increase as you scroll back up. On scrolling down the image will stop getting smaller when it reaches half its original height. This is what i have tried but its not working. Thanks.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

var windowScroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop(),
    imageHeight = jQuery('.headlogo').css('height'),
    marginHeight = jQuery('.nav.navbar').css('margin-top'),
    newMargin = marginHeight - windowScroll,
    newHeight = imageHeight - windowScroll,
    stopHeight = imageHeight / 2;

    jQuery('.headlogo').css("height", newHeight);
    jQuery('nav.navbar').css("margin-top", newMargin);

    if(newHeight == stopHeight){
        jQuery('.headlogo').css("height", stopHeight);
    }
});
```

Comment: you can try something like this [http://jsfiddle.net/xhLhY/](http://jsfiddle.net/xhLhY/) but if the scroll event move some 100 pixels at a time you may not get the same effect

Comment: @AbrahamUribe thats just what i was after thank you. If you post as an answer i can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the imageHeight and marginHeight outside the scroll event like this

```
//get original height and margin-top outside scroll     
var imageHeight = parseInt($('.headlogo').css('height')),
    stopHeight=imageHeight / 2,
    marginHeight = parseInt($('.navbar').css('margin-top'))
    stopMargin=marginHeight/2;

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
        newMargin = marginHeight - windowScroll,
        newHeight = imageHeight - windowScroll;
    if(newHeight>=stopHeight){
        $('.headlogo').css("height", newHeight);
        $('.navbar').css("margin-top", newMargin);
    }
    else{
        $('.headlogo').css("height", stopHeight);//if it scroll more set to stopHeight
        //you can also set $('.navbar').css("margin-top", stopMargin); 
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xhLhY/

Answer (score 1):

Well just to make some fun out of this question, consider this

```
 size = Math.PI/2/1000
 height(x) = maxHeight/2( 1 + Math.cos(x/size))
```

So when scroll is 0 it will be just maxHeight and when x will be 1000 it will be just maxHeight/2, and it would be maxHeight again at 2000 and so on.

```
function imgSize(maxHeight, cycle) { 
   var s = Math.PI/2/cycle 
   return function(x) { return maxHeight/2(1 + Math.cos(x/s) }
} 

var img = $('img.headlogo')
  , maxHeight = img.css('height')
  , resize = imgSize(maxHeight, 1000)

$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
   var x = $(document).scrollTop()
   img.stop().animate({ height: resize(x) }, 500)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need numeric properties you must use:

```
imageHeight = $('.headlogo').height();
```

otherwise your `imageHeight` is **`NaN`** and you can not use:

```
newHeight = imageHeight - windowScroll
```

Answer (score 0):

A JS fiddle like this will change your css class upon scrolling, so you can have one class with the image set to say 100% and one set to 50%, so as you scroll the JS will change CSS classes to the size you'd like.

```
$(function(){

var images = $(‘.yourClass’)
scrolledDistance = $(document).scrollTop()
 windowHeight = $(window).height()
 inView = scrolldDistance + windowHeight

 $(images).each(function(){
 var position = $(‘this’).position()
 topOffset = position.top
  if (inView < = topOffset ){
  $(this).css({‘opacity’:’0′}) 
  }
  })



$(window).scroll(function () { 
//update scrolled distance
scrolledDistance = $(document).scrollTop()
$(images).each(function(){
var position = $(‘this’).position()
topOffset = position.top
if (inView < = topOffset ){
$(this).animate({‘opacity’:’0′},500)
}
})
})

})
```

Comment: thanks for the response, thats how i used to have it so it would resize at a certain scroll distance, and back again at the same point, however i am trying to have it resize relative to the scroll, so as you scroll it will change incrementally, rather than in one animation at one point.