# Animated change logo size on scroll script creates a library conflict or some other loading issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, joomla

I'd like to have the logo shrink when the page scrolls down and expand to original when the page scrolls to the top. Except for the preloader with rotating icon, my code prevents the page from loading at all.

The environment is Joomla 3.8.2. The template is based on Helix 3 and I'm using the Helix 3 Custom Code form for Javascript to insert the JS.

I tried adapting a script from this page: [Jquery image height change on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706647/jquery-image-height-change-on-scroll)

Here's my version:

```
<script>
var imageHeight = 113,
stopHeight= 90,
PaddingHeight = 148,
stopPadding= 3;

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
    newPadding = PaddingHeight - windowScroll,
    newHeight = imageHeight - windowScroll;
    if(newHeight>=stopHeight){
        $('.sp-default-logo').css("height", newHeight);
        $('.logo').css("padding-top", newPadding);
    }
    else{
        $('.sp-default-logo').css("height", stopHeight);//if it scroll more set to stopHeight
        set $('.logo').css("padding-top", stopPadding);
    }
};
</script>
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
    <a href="/"><img class="sp-default-logo" src="/images/logos/logo.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Joomla uses jquery in safe mode, so the "$" should be "jQuery"". I tried both $ and jquery. Both create the same error.

The error in the console is:

> JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1 - jquery-migrate.min.js?ada38a6f4381020b76588ff4bab21f69:2
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - (index):222

Note: I first posted this to the Joomla forum, but due to lack of interest I am reposting here.

Answer (score 1):

You need use !jquery name and not $ ! Try this
I believe the jQuery live method is deprecated in the version of jQuery included in Joomla. It works in the sample code because you're loading jQuery 1.6.4. In the Joomla code try chainging this:

```
<script>
var imageHeight = 113,
stopHeight= 90,
PaddingHeight = 148,
stopPadding= 3;
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var windowScroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop(),
    newPadding = PaddingHeight - windowScroll,
    newHeight = imageHeight - windowScroll;
    if(newHeight>=stopHeight){
        jQuery('.sp-default-logo').css("height", newHeight);
        jQuery('.logo').css("padding-top", newPadding);
    }
    else{
        jQuery('.sp-default-logo').css("height", stopHeight);//if it scroll more set to stopHeight
        set jQuery('.logo').css("padding-top", stopPadding);
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks much Rafael. Unfortunately the problem remains the same. The only difference in the console is that "(index):222" changed to "(index):221". Can I assume that "index" is actually "index.php"? The file only has 49 lines, so I'm surprised about line numbers as high as 221.

Comment: print your problem and i help you plz ! print error!

Comment: The crux of the problem is that you have a library conflict or some other loading issue. It has nothing to do with your script, which could be anything. Therefore, the title is misleading. I don't mean to bust your chops. Just trying to get you the best help. remove your code and see have conflict

Comment: That's the only error that I see. How do I print it? I'm a novice, so please forgive my lack of understanding.

Comment: I do not have any error with the code removed. The title already states "...script creates a library conflict or some other loading issue". Are you suggesting that I remove "Animated change logo size on scroll"? Please bust my chops as much as necessary to get it right. :-)

Comment: I turned debug on in Joomla. The console is  now providing more details as follows:

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifierJQMIGRATE:
jQuery.fn.live() is deprecated
migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate.js?23443af0b0a808d3c7025dcc6c8d5077:45
jQuery.fn.live @ jquery-migrate.js?23443af0b0a808d3c7025dcc6c8d5077:611
(anonymous) @ k2.frontend.js?v=2.8.0&sitepath=/:257
fire @ jquery.js?23443af0b0a808d3c7025dcc6c8d5077:3232
fireWith @ jquery.js?23443af0b0a808d3c7025dcc6c8d5077:3362
ready @ jquery.js?23443af0b0a808d3c7025dcc6c8d5077:3582
completed @ jquery.js?23443af0b0a808d3c7025dcc6c8d5077:3617

Comment: console.trace
migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate.js?23443af0b0a808d3c7025dcc6c8d5077:47
jQuery.fn.live @ jquery-migrate.js?23443af0b0a808d3c7025dcc6c8d5077:611
(anonymous) @ k2.frontend.js?v=2.8.0&sitepath=/:257
fire @ jquery.js?23443af0b0a808d3c7025dcc6c8d5077:3232
fireWith @ jquery.js?23443af0b0a808d3c7025dcc6c8d5077:3362
ready @ jquery.js?23443af0b0a808d3c7025dcc6c8d5077:3582
completed @ jquery.js?23443af0b0a808d3c7025dcc6c8d5077:3617

Answer (score 0):

I switched to CSS for a much more elegant solution.

```
#sp-header.menu-fixed .logo {
  width: 261px;
  height: 85px;
  padding: 0;
}

#sp-header.menu-fixed .sp-default-logo {
  width: auto;
  height: 81px;
  margin-top: 44px;
  padding-left: 18px;  
}
```